# Is template code bloat still an issue with latest compilers/linkers

Tags: c++, templates

I read that latest versions of linkers weed out the duplicate definitions in multiple translation units, there by addressing the code bloat issue with regard to templates.

So even if I use inclusion model of compilation, my code using templates should not result in code bloat.

My query is with regard to usage of templates (meta programming) like this:

```
template <int N> int fact () 
{ 
    return fact<N-1>() * N; 
}

template <> int fact<1> () 
{ 
    return 1; 
}

int main()
{
    cout << fact<10>() << endl;
}
```

The exe size for the above code is approximately 8K. If I pass 100 instead of 10, the code size increases to 19K.

Basically I am trying to understand the coding patterns that can lead to code bloat when using templates.

EDIT: After Yakk's comment, I recompiled using -O3, the size now is almost same.

My question is, whether code bloat is no more a problem when using templates (using latest compilers and linkers) ?

Comment: Did you strip out symbols and use `-O3` or `-O2`?  Because I cannot help but think that sufficient optimization turns your code into a single print statement...

Comment: ok.. yes after compiling with -O3 the size was almost same.  So, is code bloat no more an issue when using templates ?

Comment: My experience with production level code has been in Visual Studio 2008 and 2010. I haven't noticed any bloating issues with use of templates.

Comment: @irappa Using comdat folding linkers (like the gold linker), possibly with aggressive settings (merge even if pointers are taken), may also be required.  Bloat can still occur (a vector of smart pointers to A and B may have very different `push_back` implementations because they inline the delete code, for example).

Comment: I might be completely wrong, but I would be surprised, if using templates for compile time calculations ever lead to severe code bloat (at least in cases where none of the generated code is really needed in the executable, as in your example)

Comment: @tobi303 compare iostream based "Hello, world" with C-style printf() call and weep. (5.4K vs 4.6K or roughly ~17% more 'bloated') In general, template based wrappers are a bad idea if size of the executable is a concern.

Comment: @user268396 In the example the OP is showing the template is solely used to calculate a value at compile time and it should be trivial for the compiler to realize that none of the code is needed in the executable. For any other uses of templates (i.e. generating code that is actually executed during runtime) code bloat may be an issue but here I would not know why the size of the executable would be affected at all (assuming optimizations are turned on).

Comment: Totally depends on what the template is doing. A sufficiently complex template instantiated willy-nilly will bloat. You should be able to control some of that with [explicit instantiation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template#Explicit_instantiation).

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it, with calls to non-constexpr functions, the result is being computed at runtime.  Even with the better optimization, which is probably using a precalculated result, the code will still behave as if the result was calculated at runtime, and the precalculation is not generally guaranteed.

For a metaprogramming task like this one, you force compile-time calculation of the result by relying only on constructs and results which are guaranteed available at compile-time.  The example below uses a specialized struct with a static const int data member instead of a set of nested function calls:

```
    #include <iostream>

    template <int N>
    struct fact {
        static const int value = fact<N - 1>::value * N;
    };

    template <>
    struct fact<0> {
        static const int value = 1;
    };

    int main() {
        std::cout << fact<10>::value << std::endl;
    }
```

And when I change the 10 to 100 in this version, during compilation, I see a bunch of warnings because 100! overflows a 32-bit int many times over.